# Emacs 24.3, capitalize in rectangle fill empty zone with trailing white spaces

Tags: emacs

I wrote a generic command to capitalize text. If rectangle active it converts rectangle else if region active it converts region else it converts next word

[image: Fist is my command used to test itself. Second running "M-x My-capcase. Last running M-c]

If I run it with "M-x my-capcase" it works perfectly(second block in picture), but if I run M-c it fails in rectangle case, removing initial line spaces and filling empty zone with trailing white spaces (last block in picture).

Can somebody help me please?

Comment: I've just tried it and works both ways on my Emacs configuration. What version are you using? I have GNU Emacs 24.3.50.1

Comment: One more thing you can do is check which command is run when you do `M-c`. You can do this by doing `C-h k M-c RET` this would popup a help buffer describing the command run by `M-c`. This might give a clue as to what is going wrong

Comment: I am using Emacs 24.3 for windows. So I am going to try your version.

Comment: M-c runs the correct command my-capcase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that `M-c` is bound to `cua-close-rectangle` in `cua--rectangle-keymap`, which is the keymap that is active and takes priority when in `cua-rectangle-mark-mode`. It takes priority because it is a ***minor-mode*** keymap.

The solution is to bind your command to a key in that minor mode.  If you use `M-c` for that then you will likely want to move `cua-close-rectangle` to some other key.

---

BTW, `C-h M-k` (command `describe-keymap`), from library [`help-fns.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/help-fns%2b.el), is a big help in situations like this.  `C-h M-k cua--rectangle-keymap` shows you all of the key bindings in that minor-mode keymap.